# How to get <audio> tag information?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

like title, subtitle, singer, Album, Bit rate  etc..

[wiki - MP3 tag infomation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#ID3_and_other_tags)

[wiki - ID3(mp3 metadata format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)

I search a lot.. but I can't get answer.

only searched how to play,stop,reload audio..

browser not support that?

Comment: This is a great question. I havent found any info on how to get this information or documentation, and I'm interested in finding out.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want to display Title, Subtitle Album details of each audio on a page?

Comment: @Habo no, i don't want display all details of each audio. i just want know can i do that?

Comment: @HaBo Yeah I think so. They just seem to want to get those pieces of information for a specific audio element

Comment: There is no default way, but you can always have workarounds for that. what you have tried so far? can you paste any of your sample code here?

Comment: @HaBo i don't have any sample code. because i totally don't know how to do.. all i searched just teach me how to 'autoplay' 'stop' 'muted'....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One more library available  at
https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader

In its simplest form:

```
ID3.loadTags("filename.mp3", function() {
    var tags = ID3.getAllTags(filename);
    alert(tags.artist + " - " + tags.title + ", " + tags.album);
});
```

by specifying specific tags:

```
ID3.loadTags("filename.mp3", function() {
    var tags = ID3.getAllTags(filename);
    alert(tags.COMM.data + " - " + tags.TCON.data + ", " + tags.WXXX.data);
},
{tags: ["COMM", "TCON", "WXXX"]});
```

or even by specifying shortcuts instead of cryptic tags:

```
ID3.loadTags("filename.mp3", function() {
    var tags = ID3.getAllTags(filename);
    alert(tags.comment + " - " + tags.track + ", " + tags.lyrics);
},
{tags: ["comment", "track", "lyrics"]});
```

Demo here http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net/libraries/id3/#demo

Comment: This library is actually based off the one @Turnerj linked to. The advantage of this one is that it does work in Opera and supports AAC metadata as well.

Comment: https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader "This project has been superseded by jsmediatags and is no longer under maintainance, [...]"
https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can with the right libraries! [Reading ID3 tags with Javascript](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript.html) and [here is the demo](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/id3/)

Using the ID3.js library, your Javascript would be similar to:

```
// URL of the mp3 file (must be on the same domain!)
var file = "mymusicfile.mp3";
// define your own callback function
function mycallback() {
    // either call the ID3.getAllTags([file]) function which returns an object holding all the tags
    alert(
        "All tags in this file: " + ID3.getAllTags(file).toSource()
    );
    // or call ID3.getTag([file], [tag]) to get a specific tag
    alert(
        "Title: " + ID3.getTag(file, "title") + " by artist: " + ID3.getTag(file, "artist")
    );
}
ID3.loadTags(file, mycallback);
```

Based on the post in the first link I provided, it does not work in Opera browsers and is limited to ID3v1 which by the words of the poster:

*"it's only capable of reading (the rather lacking) ID3v1 tags since these are very simple compared to the more fleshed out and robust ID3v2 tags"*